# Почему регулярное выражение b(\w+?)\1\b находит catcat — слово, состоящее из двух одинаковых частей

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Помогите понять почему так именно так работает регулярное выражение.

Решал задачу по регуляркам, суть была в поиске слов состоящих из двух одинаковых частей(`catcat, wqewqe`), в итоге подобрал случайно регулярку которая работает, но не могу понять почему так, вот она

```
\b(\w+?)\1\b
```

Ход моих мыслей: сначала мы ищем слова и разбиваем их по группам, но вот как обращение к первой группе которую нашли, найдет нам в тексте слово `catcat`. По всей видимости я что-то упускаю(наверное как работают группы) объясните пожалуйста как отрабатывает данная регулярка и почему она находит слова из двух одинаковых частей.

Comment: вы находите не слово, а строку, начинающуюся с разрыва между словами, т.е. регулярка берет букву "c", смотрит что за ней, не подошло, возвращается назад, берет в первое слово "ca", не подошло. наконец берет "cat" и видит за ним повтор, подошло, проверяет окончание слова

Comment: кстати, в вашем случае ленивый режим не нужен (т.е. можно так `\b(\w+)\1\b`), потому что ваша регулярка все равно ищет целое слово, состоящее из двух повторов, так что она не сможет захватить в первой части больше, чем нужно для того, чтобы вторая часть слова совпала с ней

Comment: Если хотя бы немного дружите с английским, то могу порекомендовать [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), который кроме того что позволяет протестировать online ваш RegEx, но еще и объясняет каждый шаг на английском. [Вот пример...](https://regex101.com/r/Shf3IO/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша регулярка `\b(\w+?)\1\b`

- `\b...\b` - ищем все слово
- `\b(\w+?)` - с начала слова берем одну или больше букв, но не жадно
- `\1` - ссылаемся на первую группу. Т.е. после первой группы должна идти еще одна такая же последовательность символов.

Т.е. Вашу регулярку можно представить так

```
\b \w+?  \w+ \b
  | 1  || 2 |
```

с условием, что 1 == 2